# Django: models.FilePathField -> alphabetical order

Tags: django, admin, alphabetical-sort

I defined an image field like that:

```
image = models.FilePathField(path="xxx",recursive=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

The order of the images is random when I use Django Admin. How can I sort them alphabetically?

EDIT:
The objects have other fields, too. But a field is a dropbox with all the images in the directory. These images are not sorted in alphabetical order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) option to the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['image']
```

**UPDATE**: The simplest way to always get a sorted list of the images is to use the [`Meta.ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#ordering) option in the model definition:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FilePathField(path="xxx", recursive=True,
                                 blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['image']
```

**UPDATE 2**: If you want to order by name the only the foreign key field in the admin form then override the [`formfield_for_foreignkey()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "image":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Image.objects.all().order_by("image")
        return super(MyAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
                                                  db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want the sort list, but the dropbox with images. There is a dropbox with the includes image files, but these files are random ordered.

Comment: I see. But the elements have names, too. The list should be ordered by name. The FilePathField has no option for ordering (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield)

Comment: `ordering` is the option of the `Model` not of the `FilePathField`. Anyway, see the second update of my answer.

Comment: In your 2nd update, image has to be a foreign key, but actually it isn't. I'll try to implement later. Thanks for your help

Comment: In the second update I mean the admin of the model with `image` and `weblink` fields.  As I understood from your screenshot this model has the `image` field as the foreign key.